# Realtek Audio Manager on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, realtek

I have Realtek soundcard on my HP-430 notebook but I can't seems able to have it's HD sound experience. The sound is lousy compared to Windows 7.

I've been searching all over the 'www' to find any Realtek Audio Manager for linux or some sort of it but have no luck. All I could find is Realtek Soundcard driver form their website.

I don't want go back to Windows 7 because of it. Would anyone help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, finally my problem is *assumed* solved.

I updated ALSA driver with [**this**](http://www.stchman.com/tools/alsa/alsa_setup.sh) driver update script. 
And then installed PulseAudio Equalizer as explained on [**this thread.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142385/graphical-sound-equalizer-eq-for-ubuntu-12-04)

And now, the Audio Setup does showed ALC270 soundcard.

The sound quality is almost as good as in Win7.

[image: Audio Setup]

[image: Mixer]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install drivers using Additional Drivers?
Can you see your driver when clicking on the speaker icon (the one you click to adjust volume)? If you can't, your driver may not installed.

Try typing Additional Drivers into search and it should pop up, then launch it.
Now activate your drivers by clicking on its name, then choosing activate. It should then start downloading and installing that driver for you.

(I have Realtek Audio too)

If you need help, let me know.

Oh yah, its a good idea to update your post by clicking the "edit" just right under your post.

Comment: It seems like that my driver has not been installed. I clicked the speaker icon and the one which came out is Built-in Audio Analog Stereo. The Additional Driver says that 'No proprietary are used on this system'. I've followed the instructions guide in this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/97224/5-1-surround-system-subwoofer-not-working step 1 to 4.